# Sharepoint Navigation Link redirects to Home Page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am facing issues with the Navigation Link from the Navigation where it should redirect to the a different page, but for some reason it redirects to the Home Page, Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume the link in the left navigation does not get the right URL. You can edit the destination of the navigation link easily.

Check the detailed steps here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca

**Update**:
I will upload a simple demo about editing the navigation link:
[image]

Comment: Unable to find anything useful in there, Can you help me find that what i should be looking for?

Comment: @TejasThite, I upload a gif about editing the navigation link if it goes to a classical experience.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, that has helped

Comment: @TejasThite, Glad to be help. Please accept the rely answer if it solves your issue.